# Apache, redirect directory but keep sub-directory un-redirected

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

In Apache, is it possible that I can redirect a directory on my website to a new address, but keep sub-directories un-redirected?

For example, I wish to redirect accesses to files under

```
https://www.example.com/folder/ to
https://www.newexample.com/folder/
```

i.e. from

```
https://www.example.com/folder/abc.html to
https://www.newexample.com/folder/abc.html
```

But keep the access to its sub-folders unchanged?
https://www.example.com/folder/subfolder/123.html will not be redirected.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude subfolder requests with a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/.*?/
RewriteRule ^folder/ https://www.newexample.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: That's brilliant, works like a charm. Thanks so much Dietsche.